# Adding a button text to an sqlite3 database in python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have one button in tkinter called transfer. When a user clicks the button, I want the word to populate the table in the database. Also, I would like the amount to be incremented by one. I know I can use a for loop for this, but I'm a bit stuck at how to implement this.

Below is a simple front end GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
#call the backend script
import backend_practice

def add_command():
    backend_practice.insert

    # unsure about what to put in here, I've tried putting the name (title, amount) 
    # but it get an error saying the variable is not defined

window=Tk()

# this button text "transfer" needs to poulate the title fiels in the sqlite database

buttontransfer = Button(window, text = "transfer", command = add_command)
buttontransfer.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4, width=175,height=35)
```

Bellow is the backend:

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, amount 
    integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
def insert(title, amount):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book values (NULL,?,?)", (title, amount))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update(id, title, amount):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, amount=? WHERE id = ?", ( title, amount, id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

connect()
```

Comment: `backend_practice.insert` doesn't do anything. To call a function you need to use parenthesis and pass the required arguments.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the.get method. So title.get inside parenthesis, but it doesn't find title or amount. I've tried naming the button title and amount but they it says button has no attribute of get. So I tried to add a get method to the button which never worked.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any entry widgets. Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I dont need entry widgets though, i need a button that submits the data in the button when the button is clicked?

Comment: Submits _what_ data? Your program doesn't have any data to submit.

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear here. The data is actually the writing in the box. Its like going to a bank machine, you see £10, £20 £40 ect in a button, you click the button and you get 10.

Comment: So in the code above, the writing in the box 'transfer' is the information.

Comment: I don't understand. Your function requires a title and an amount. I don't see a "box" anywhere with that information.  You have one button with the word "transfer".

Comment: Thanks Brian, got it sorted.